# Resize iframe without aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a responsive iframe that will get a map, but when I resize the browser, it resizes using the aspect ratio, and I would like him to remain filling the entire space. As in this example: http://dev.fhmp.net/tailorfit/demo/, in the case where the overflow is crop.

Today it looks like this:

```css
.iframe-rwd  {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.iframe-rwd iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <section id="container">
        {% include "main/header.html" %}
        {% include "main/sidebar.html" %}
        <section id="main-content">
            <section style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" class="wrapper">
                <div class="iframe-rwd">
                    <iframe
                            name="main-content"
                            src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the past i've just set the iframe width to 100%, if you have the iframe in a responsive container than it will always take that width and retain whatever height you set the iframe to.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is from Dave Rupert / Chris Coyier (I think). It requires a wrapper div but works pretty well.

**HTML**

```
<div class="iframe-rwd">
        <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Seattle,+WA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=seattle&amp;sll=37.822293,-85.76824&amp;sspn=6.628688,16.907959&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Seattle,+King,+Washington&amp;z=11&amp;ll=47.60621,-122.332071&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Seattle,+WA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=seattle&amp;sll=37.822293,-85.76824&amp;sspn=6.628688,16.907959&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Seattle,+King,+Washington&amp;z=11&amp;ll=47.60621,-122.332071" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.iframe-rwd  {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 65.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.iframe-rwd iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/gnpors6f/) doesn't work :( I need the map fill the screen size, and when he does not have resize aspect ratio. In other words, I need a div of the screen size and a map inside the div.

Comment: so late for this but, `height: 100vh; width: 100vw` would be viewport height & width